# C# calculate total time worked with TimeSpan

Tags: c#, floating-point

So there is an existing codebase which calculates the total time worked per month.

#### What the code is doing:

- iterates through all the working days entries
- retreives the value of net work time which is in format: `HH:mm`
- calculates the minutes out of the net work time string
- formats the net work time to the report day row (back again)
- adds the daily calculated minutes to monthly total
- formats the total monthly minutes to the report totals row

#### Problem

The code randomly calculates the data properly.
When data is calculated properly:

- the total is calculated properly,
- the day rows adds up to the total value

When data is not properly calculated:

- the total has always 1h less
- every entry which does not have minutes part has 1h less which means that it does not even adds up to the wrongly calculated total

To resolve the problem we obviously need to get rid of type conversion from `double` (`ts.TotalHours`) to `int`

But the questions are:

1. Why the calculations are wrong randomly (or this is just my impression)?
2. How to mimic the wrong calculation behavour in unit tests?

Based on this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47302758/1498401 it seems that floating point calculation might be platform specific so additional information about server configuration:

- There are 2 fronted servers with win 2k12r2

```cs
static int totalMinutesCounter { get; set; }

public static string GetFormatedTime(string s, out int minutesCounter)
{
    minutesCounter = 0;

    if (s == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    int workedTimeMinutes = GetNumberOfMinutes(s);

    if (workedTimeMinutes < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("workedTimeHours", "Negative values not allowed");
    }

    minutesCounter = workedTimeMinutes;

    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, workedTimeMinutes, 0);

    return ((int)ts.TotalHours).ToString() + ts.ToString(@"\:mm");
}

static string GetFormatedTimeFromMinutes(int minutes, ref int minutesCounter)
{
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, minutes, 0);

    minutesCounter += minutes;

    return ((int)ts.TotalHours).ToString() + ts.ToString(@"\:mm");
}

private static int GetNumberOfMinutes(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    char[] charSeparators = new char[] { ':' };
    string[] result = s.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string sh = result[0].ToString();
    string sm = result[1].ToString();
    int hh = int.Parse(sh);
    int mm = int.Parse(sm);

    return mm + 60 * hh;
}
```

My unit test i would like to see failing ;)

````cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    List<string> times = new List<string>()
    {
        "11:30","12:00","08:00","09:30","07:00","11:00","09:30","11:00","11:30","07:00","08:00","09:30","10:30","09:00","09:45","08:00","10:15","11:00","10:00"
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        foreach (var s in times)
        {
            int minutesCounter = 0;

            var rowValue = GetFormatedTime(s, out minutesCounter);

            totalMinutesCounter += minutesCounter;
        }

        int temp = 0;
        var result = GetFormatedTimeFromMinutes(totalMinutesCounter, ref temp);
        totalMinutesCounter = 0;

        Assert.AreEqual("184:00", result);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: do you use 24 or 12 hours system ? and what is the table data structure (with datatype) that you are getting these timespans from ?

Comment: also, we need a raw data sample from the application source. Without these two requirements, I believe you won't have a concrete answer to solve this issue.

Comment: @iSR5 we use 24 hour system. The concrete sample from application source code is overcomplicated, but the thing it does, it loops throught the sharepoint list timesheet entries, gets day net time in format HH:mm which is correct and then does the calculation as i've done it in this unit test scenario.

Comment: your comment made things clear and enough for me. Your main issue is that you're getting a 24 hour clock system, and treat it as 12 hour clock system, without the proper conversions. If you add "00:05" to your tests, it will only add 5 minutes to the results, which is false. it should add 1 hour and 5 minutes. So,  you need to deal with it as 24 hours system or do proper conversion. the easiest way is to use `DateTime` and then work from there.

Comment: I am confused. The times list contains the entries with net work time in single day, ie. 10:00 means 10 hours and 0 minutes, 13:15 means 13 hours and 15 minutes. So i don't see it that 00:05 entry should add 1 hour and 5 minutes

Comment: it is a typo. I meant 12 hour and 5 minutes. where "00:05" is 5 minutes passed midnight in 24 hour clock system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does your code pointlessly reinvent the wheel? Microsoft provides [methods to convert `string`s to `DateTime`s](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime); why not use those instead of your own clunky `GetNumberOfMinutes`? Or perhaps even better: [convert the `string` directly to a `TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse).

On the subject of `GetNumberOfMinutes`: why even do `string sh = result[0].ToString();?` The result of `spring.Split` is an array of `string`s, why then the need to convert a `string` to a `string`? And that's just one of the things that are wrong with that method, there are several more.

---

The whole flow of your code is IMHO needlessly complex. Why not simply convert each `time` to a `TimeSpan`, thus getting a `List<TimeSpan>`, then [calculate the amount of minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703056/648075), add those up, and then convert those to a "readable" format?

I don't even understand why you do this: `((int)ts.TotalHours).ToString() + ts.ToString(@"\:mm");`. Surely this can be [expressed much more elegantly and readable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan).

---

On a general note: use proper, self-explanatory names for your variables, and not `ts` or `sh` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your time, of course you're right, this code is wrong in many ways, but what i am really curious about is why it gives wrong/random calculations when deployed on web servers and does not in unit tests.

Comment: @tinamou Your bug is likely caused by converting vs casting, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754251/converting-a-double-to-an-int-in-c-sharp . What you should do is research how to do predictable rounding -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409965/c-sharp-rounding-down-to-nearest-integer -- instead of trying to write tests that reproduce the bug.